# Derivation of Noether's Theorem

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, symmetry, field-theory, noethers-theorem

I have a question concerning the derivation of Noether's theorem in Peskin & Schroeders introduction to QFT. Below is a picture of the first part of it.

The proof then proceeds by saying that one term vanishes because of the euler-lagrange equations. It seems to me like what they are saying is that the term only vanishes because we have a symmetry transformation. But to me this is the general behaviour of the lagrangian under a transformation and the term in the brackets will always vanish, regardless of the transformation. So my question is: Why does the term in the square brackets in eq. (2.11) only vanish for symmetry transformations?

[image: Peskin]

Comment: You're just misreading the text - they're not claiming that the E-L expression only vanishes for symmetry variations.

Comment: This may help: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/56905/19976

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The writing is certainly less clear than it ought to be.
Your instincts are right; they just didn't explain it well.
In particular, they're not saying that the term in brackets
only vanishes for symmetry transformations.  It always
vanishes for a field obeying the Euler-Lagrange equations.

What they're really saying is:

1. A continuous transformation can be written as equation (2.9)
2. The equation of motion will be invariant under that continuous transformation *if* the Lagrangian changes as equation (2.10)
3. Let's see how the Lagrangian actually changes under the transformation of (2.9)
4. It changes as a term that looks like $\alpha \partial_\mu \mathcal{J}^\mu$ plus a term that goes to zero because of the Euler-Lagrange equations ***for the original, un-transformed system***
5. The actual change we get is the change we demanded for the Lagrangian to be invariant up to a 4-divergence
6. Therefore, the continuous transformation is a symmetry transformation

The text immediately following what the OP included says

> The second term [in equation (2.11)] vanishes by the
>   Euler-Lagrange equation.  We set the remaining term equal to
>   $\alpha \partial_\mu \mathcal{J}^\mu$ and find
>   \begin{equation}
>   \partial_\mu j^\mu(x) = 0\,
>   \qquad \mathrm{for} \qquad
>   j^\mu(x) = \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}} {\partial
>   (\partial_\mu \phi)} \Delta \phi - \mathcal{J}^\mu.
> \end{equation}

This really makes it look like they're saying that $j^\mu$ is identically zero; in fact, I would argue that that's the most reasonable
reading of the text.  What they *should have* said is that
we get the generic result
\begin{equation}
  \Delta \mathcal{L} = \partial_\mu \left( \frac{\partial
  \mathcal{L}} {\partial (\partial_\mu \phi)} \Delta \phi
  \right) \tag{A}
\end{equation}
whenever $\phi$ satisfies the Euler-Lagrange equations, but
to call $\Delta \phi$ a symmetry transformation we *require*
the existence of some *other* field $\mathcal{J}^\mu$ such
that
\begin{equation}
  \Delta \mathcal{L} = \partial_\mu \mathcal{J}^\mu \tag{B}
\end{equation}
regardless of whether or not the Euler-Lagrange equations
are satisfied.  Again, (A) is generically true for any
differentiable Lagrangian and field satisfying the E-L
equations.  On the other hand, **you have to use the
particular form of $\mathcal{L}$ and the particular form of
$\Delta \phi$ to decide if (B) is true in any particular
case**.  (Also note that $\mathcal{J}^\mu = 0$ is perfectly
acceptable.)

It probably would have been clearer if P&S had begun by
moving the explanation of what a symmetry transformation is
[the four sentences up to equation (2.10)] to a previous
paragraph and expanding on it.  Then they could introduce a
continuous transformation and show how the Lagrangian
changes.  But why bother editing a piece of text for
clarity, when it's only explaining something as frivolous
and useless as Noether's Theorem?  ;)

These issues are made much clearer in [@joshphysics's version of the
proof](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/56905/8007) — in particular with his introduction of separate
$\mathcal{J}^\mu$ and $\mathcal{K}^\mu$ vector fields.  They
look like they perform the same function, and yet they're
different, as he explains in the ["Important Notes"
section](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/56851/noethers-current-expression-in-peskin-and-schroeder/56905#MathJax-Element-34-Frame)
at the bottom of his answer, and in [some of the
comments](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/56851/noethers-current-expression-in-peskin-and-schroeder#comment-115571).

I also highly recommend the
excellent "Quantum Field Theory for the Gifted Amateur", which does
a typically superb job on Noether's Theorem, and is really what I think should be
the standard text.  The title is deceptive because it's
aimed at professional physicists, just not current
professional quantum-field theorists.  I encourage you to at
least read [the other
answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/56905/8007), or
even take up "Gifted Amateur" if you really want to
understand QFT.

Comment: something as frivolous and useless as Noether's Theorem? LOL

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer.
It seems I understood the steps correctly, I just didn't understand what they were trying to prove. After your explanation I now believe that any transformation of the form (2.9) is a symmetry transformation that will leave the e.o.m. invariant. Is that correct? As I am typing it, I am already less convinved of this, as it looks like the most general form one could write a transformation of the field. So maybe as a follow up question: If I did understand your answer correctly, what would a transformation look like which is not a symmetry transformation?

Comment: Again, very good question; you're thinking clearly about this, and any confusion you're experiencing seems to be coming from poor explanations that you're getting (including mine). I've edited my answer to explain this a little more.

Comment: Ironically, I ended up at this answer after searching more resources due to having been _very_ confused by the discussion in "Gifted Amateur". 